# Firestore compound query not working flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem using compound query in firebase flutter, the following query:

```
int priceMax, priceMin;
String product;
searchQuery =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products")
        .where("price", isLessThanOrEqualTo: priceMax)
        .where("price", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: priceMin)
        .orderBy("price")
        .orderBy("name")
        .startAt([product])
        .endAt([product+'\uf8ff']);
```

When I make a query with **price** only it works right and when I make for **product** only it also works but when I make both together it doesn't give any results or errors.

Please note that I created index at firestore indexes for this query.

this is error log:

```
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180673922, downTime=180673883 } moveCount:1
I/Counters(20223): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180675337, downTime=180675337 } moveCount:0
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180675472, downTime=180675337 } moveCount:17
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180676056, downTime=180676056 } moveCount:0
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180676101, downTime=180676056 } moveCount:0
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180677640, downTime=180677640 } moveCount:0
D/MIUIInput(20223): [MotionEvent] ViewRootImpl { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, pointerCount=1, eventTime=180677734, downTime=180677640 } moveCount:0
I/Counters(20223): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown any code that checks for errors.  You should always do that, and log the error you get.  That should all be included in your question.

Comment: I have just add my run error log. @DougStevenson

Comment: `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` This means the UI / widget is not constructed correctly. The problem might not be related to querying Firebase but to how to constructs the UI.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the Firestore query.  You still haven't shown any code that checks for and logs possible errors from your query.

Comment: Results is shown successfully for any query except this compound query @Dabbel

Comment: I found that I wrapped Google Map with Expanded that causes ```Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget``` I updated the run log at the original question description. @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run a query with two relational conditions on two fields, which is not supported in Firestore. According to the [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) in the documentation:

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`), your first ordering must be on the same field

While it doesn't explicitly name them, the `startAt` `startAfter`, `endAt` and `endBefore` operators also are considered range operators.